# Hibernate - Soft Delete - Multiple parameters

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have problem with soft delete when I'm trying to "delete" rows based on multiple parameters in `@SqlDelete` anotation.

Here is my code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "department")
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
//Override the default Hibernation delete and set the deleted flag rather than deleting the record from the db.
@SQLDelete(sql="UPDATE department SET valid_to = NOW(), active_f = 0 WHERE id = ? OR parent_department_id = ?")
//Filter added to retrieve only records that have not been soft deleted.
@Where(clause="valid_to IS NULL and active_f = 1")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Department implements Serializable {
    ...  
}
```

When I run this code I got an error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not
>   execute statement
>         at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:62)
>         at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3400)
>         at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3630)
>         at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:114)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:465)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:351)
>         at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
>         at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
>         at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1258)
>         at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
>         at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:77)
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
>         ... 136 common frames omitted
>       Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Statement parameter 2 not set.
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:896)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:885)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.serverExecute(ServerPreparedStatement.java:1158)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ServerPreparedStatement.java:780)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2073)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2009)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5094)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1994)
>         at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
>         at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The error is thrown because you have more than one parameter in @SQLDelete annotation. There is no way to set parameters of @SQLDelete query. Hibernate internally picks up the value passed during the session.delete call.

It is not a good idea to delete a data based on something other than primary key. So, if you just use the following it will work like a charm.

```
@SQLDelete(sql="UPDATE department SET valid_to = NOW(), active_f = 0 WHERE id = ?")
```

Comment: I know that but I was wondering is there a way to do that with multiple parameters....

Comment: There is no such way to implement multiple parameters in @SQLDelete :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Where along with @SqlDelete but then the condition u define in where would be used to execute all queries. Not sure how can we make it particular to @SqlDelete.